# Switch WPF UI controls dynamically

Tags: wpf, user-interface, wpf-controls

I need to develop a simple WPF application. In the UI window, There are Labels and Text Blocks towards the left and Buttons towards the right.

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih6T5.png)

Based on a config setting (whether the user is left-handed or right-handed)  I need to switch the controls, Buttons towards the left and Labels and Text Blocks towards the right.

[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAELW.png)

Can you please recommend a good way to address this requirement?

Comment: Define 2 templates, choose the right one based on config setting. There are lot of samples out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what the scope of the app is likely to be.

2 alternatives:

1)

I think it likely as an app grows that there will be more than just buttons.

I would probably build a usercontrol which encapsulates this behaviour for a label and control. The usercontrol uses a static to decide where the textblocks are positioned but would look something like the row edit control in this:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/WPF-Entity-Framework-MVVM-78cdc204

Which is a usercontrol has a contentpresenter in it so you can put any control you like ( such as a button ) "in" it and set a dependency property for the label.

2)

Define 2 contentcontrol templates similar to the one used in this:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28597.aspx

Put them in separate resource dictionaries and give them the same key.

Merge into application.current.resources the appropriate resource dictionary and hence style.

Seeing as this is an app setting, this is presumably a start up thing. People don't just change their "handedness" dynamically.  So you could probably use these as staticresource. If they're realistically going to change at run time then I think this would be a bit more involved because you'd need to force re render of a view.

Answer (score 0):

2 Templates are probably the right and stylish solution here as @RajN said.

Also you can define a grid with 2 columns and switch the property 'Grid.Column' of each controls accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best way, but I managed to achieve this using a grid as per your suggestions. Thank you all for your valuable feedback.

I switched the columns and changed the widths accordingly.

```
        if (AppSettings.IsLeft)
        {
            parentGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = new GridLength(400, GridUnitType.Pixel);
            parentGrid.ColumnDefinitions[1].Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);

            Grid.SetColumn(buttonGrid,0);
            Grid.SetRow(buttonGrid,0);

            Grid.SetColumn(contentGrid,1);
            Grid.SetRow(contentGrid,0);
        }
```